# Looking for a manga about a high school student who wants to take over the world

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is about a guy in high school whose goal is to take over the world/rule it. He's basically a delinquent, though not like a genius or anything. I read the manga so long ago and I forgot this name.

These were a couple story arcs:

- He fights this gang and one of the people knows martial arts, he actually manages to get glass in his foot, but still beats the guy in the gang who knows martial arts.
- Another plot is he like plays in a rock band.

There was another manga using the same main protagonist, but in this story, he's God's son. The two mangas have the same main character but are not linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably [Hareluya](https://myanimelist.net/anime/4211/Hareluya_II_Boy).

The character :

- is the son of god
- a delinquant
- want to conquer the world

Comment: That is exactly it! Thank you so much!